# Unexpected identifier in express app on npm start

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have a node application using Express and has the following code in `app.js` file

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

module.exports = app
```

and I have another `js` file which is stored in `bin/www` and it has following content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

import app from '../app'
import http from 'http'
import DEBUG from 'debug'

const debug = DEBUG('tmp:server')


/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

const port = '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Now in my `package.json` file, I have the npm start command as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
```

But when I run `npm start`, I am getting the following error:

```
import app from '../app'
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cloud-search-server@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cloud-search-server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Actually, the `app.js` file had more code, but I have removed most of it for debugging. It is not working even with this code. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use export default

```
export default app;
```

And in package.json, add type "module"

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
"type": "module"
```

Comment: which file do I need to give this? I have added it to `app.js`, but the error is still there.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck after adding this too.